# programming FPGA using ethernet

Tags: fpga, bootloader

I have to program the FPGA using bootloader over ethernet connection.
My questions is that do I need to remove the inputs from the FPGA while programming its flash.

Regards
Uzmeed

Answer (score 0):

I use the following [Ethernet FPGA cores](https://www.fpga-cores.com/cores/) with necessary Ethernet functionality, flash programmer and more.

These cores supports this [remote programming tool](https://www.fpga-cores.com/software/fpga-programmer/). The core works great and are very easy to use. Free to download.

Comment: I have the ethernet fpga core . My question is if I am programming the Flash and my FPGA is receiving data from I/O ,will it cause some problem like damaging the FPGA. Logically it should not because FPGA still offers all necessary termination to signal while Flash is being programmed

Comment: @uzmeed, No I don't see why the FPGA should be damage.

Answer (score 0):

Is the flash external or internal to FPGA? If the flash is external, most likely FPGA will have dedicated serial configuration interface. Now really depending on the sensitivity of other I/O and the speeds you are operating, if the board isn't designed right, fast edge rates on SPI interface can inject noise into other I/O channels(For example if there is an analog data line close by which is monitored through an ADC by FPGA). Highly unlikely that any of these will "damage" your FPGA, but if you care about data integrity on these I/O lines, even during flash is programmed, then that could be impacted. If this is an internal flash, obviously none of these would be an issue.